# Firefox will hide after minimizing

Tags: firefox, kubuntu, window-management

I installed Firefox 3.18 and created a new launcher and removed Firefox 4. When I try to minimize all the windows will hide and I can't find them.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

While this may not correct the issue with Firefox, it may help you better deal with it.  Tell me, when Firefox is minimized as you have described, what does <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> buy you?  Are you able to select Firefox and begin working with it again?

Please let me know if I have missed the gist of your question, as I am having a little difficulty understanding exactly what you are asking.

Comment: thanks mr .DoR , i ment that when i tried to minimize the firefox after i cant get the firefox because i cant find it to maximize .